# lucene.net filtering on multiple fields

Tags: c#, lucene, lucene.net

Following is my schema

Product_Name (Analyzed),Category (Analyzed)

**Scenario:**
I want to search those products whose category is exactly "Cellphones & Accessories" and Product_Name is "sam*"

Equivalent SQL Query is

```
select * from products
where Product_Name like '%sam%' and Category='Cellphones & Accessories'
```

I am using lucene.net.
I need equivalent `lucene.net` statement.

Answer (score 0):

As this is a few months old I'll be brief (I can expand if you're still interested)...

If you want to have an exact match to Category then do not analyze. Analyzers will chop the string up into bits which are then searchable. Matching case can be problematic so maybe just the lowercase analyzer would work for that field.
It might be useful to have several fields analyzed in different ways so that different queries can be used.

NOTE: "sam*" is not equivalent to "%sam%"

Do you want "sam" to be a prefix ie "sample" or a word "the sam product"?
If it's a word then a no stopword analyzer should be fine.
A nice trick is to create many fields (with the same name) with variations of the name. Probably with just a lower case analyzer

name: "some sample product"

name: "sample product"

name" "product"

Then have a look at "prefix queries". a query of (name:sam) would then match.

Also have a look at the PerFieldAnalyzerWrapper in order to use a different analyzer for each field.